# Python libusb give me OSError: exception: access violation reading

Tags: python, usb

I have been trying to intersect usb input with libusb. I can successfully detect and connect to the device but unable to read from the device.

I have a monitoring device which i works perfectly with it own software. but i need to get the data to python for further analysis.

```
import usb.core
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x09da, idProduct=0xc10a)
import usb1
with usb1.USBContext() as context:
    handle = context.openByVendorIDAndProductID(0x09DA,0xC10A,skip_on_error=True)
Ep = dev[0][(0,0)][0]
while True:
    data = handle.bulkRead(0x5, 8)
```

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      4 Ep = dev[0][(0,0)][0]
      5 while True:
----> 6     data = handle.bulkRead(0x5, 8)

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\usb1__init__.py in bulkRead(self, endpoint, length, timeout)
   1567         data, data_buffer = create_binary_buffer(length)
   1568         try:
-> 1569             transferred = self._bulkTransfer(endpoint, data, length, timeout)
   1570         except USBErrorTimeout as exception:
   1571             exception.received = data_buffer[:exception.transferred]

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\usb1__init__.py in _bulkTransfer(self, endpoint, data, length, timeout)
   1516         try:
   1517             mayRaiseUSBError(libusb1.libusb_bulk_transfer(
-> 1518                 self.__handle, endpoint, data, length, byref(transferred), timeout,
   1519             ))
   1520         except USBErrorTimeout as exception:

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000040

Comment: Could be related to this https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/203 Check your library version

Comment: Tried with older versions as they suggest. but it didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had similar OSError when using usb.core.

```
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000024
```

And I tried couple of changes suggested here in - https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/203

1. Used patch from git, since its not released in PyPi
   https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb
2. Used libusb to 1.0.22 DLL

this reduced the frequency of the exception occurrence but didnt solve for me.

Then, I tried this -

```
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
dev.set_configuration()  # added this line
```

I havent seen the exception to occur so far. Hope this helps.

I havent tried but, maybe try applying this patch (suggested in https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/203)
 -
https://github.com/jonasmalacofilho/liquidctl/commit/e1cdcb686e50231e425f0121f880289420510c8d